# Dreamweaver CS6 Contact Form design without label

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I know the process of creating a normal Contact Form using Dreamweaver CS6.

But for my contact form, I don't want labels like Name: Email: Message:
I want to state the label inside the textfield as initial value. When you click on the Name Textfield, the "Name" label disappears.

How do I make this effect?

Comment: How about leave the label blank? <label for="email">Your Email: </label>  ------ <label for="email"></label>

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the placeholder attribute in your input tag.

```
<input type="text" ... placeholder="First Name">
```

In Dreamweaver, you can find this attribute in the properties panel:

[image: Dreamweaver placeholder attribute]

Answer (score 0):

You can use place holders in the fields boxes but i do not recommend that.

here is a link.

http://www.pardot.com/faqs/forms/placeholders-and-labels/

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want a label outside the input this is how it is normally achieved:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Label Goes Here!">
```

if you notice when you input text it will dissapear and when you remove your text the placeholder will re appear!